# Парсинг Данных из mp3 с тегами без использования сторонних модулей

Tags: python, парсер, mp3

Из mp3 Трека через считывание метаданных и декода их, получил строку

> "ID3   klTALB   -  ÿþT h e   P l a t i n u m   S e r i e s   I TPE1
>     ÿþa u d i o m a c h i n e COMM   :  engÿþ  ÿþO r c h e s t r a l 
>   -   E p i c   A c t i o n TCOM   -  ÿþP a u l   D i n l e t i r _ ( A S C A P )"

Далее я заменил через re.sub все сторонние символы на пустые символы кроме "a-zA-Zа-яА-Я ()1234567890" и получил строку

> "ID3klTALBThe Platinum Series ITPE1audiomachineCOMMengOrchestral  Epic
>   ActionTCOMPaul Dinletir(ASCAP)TIT13Naomiville Music (ASCAP)"

Мне нужно выдернуть название после каждого тега, (TALB,TRE1,COMM,TCOM). Не знаю как это реализовать. Написал Алгоритм для того, что бы может быть, на ранней стадии , где-нибудь, сделать по другому.

P.S Предлагать готовые модули с парсингом метаданных Mp3 Не надо.

Comment: Id3tag вполне себе нормальный модуль, а изобретение велосипеда не обосновано.

Comment: Изобретение велосипеда - это весело, кроме того я как-то пытался найти хоть какую-то рабочую библиотеку, а кончилось написанием своей в 20 строк. Проблема в том, что автор зачем-то ломает всю структуру тегов, а потом в остатках пытается найти что-то нужное. И что ему посоветовать - я даже не знаю.

Comment: bukkjot, Я поэтому и написал как я делал сначала, для того, что бы мб люди подскажут как по другому сделать, если можете, подскажите начинающему.

0andriy, В этом суть задания которое я получил, распарсить без модулей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
slovaboli = ["TALB", "TPE1", "COMM", "TCOM", "TIT13", "(ASCAP)"]
c = list("vhTALBThe Platinum Series ITPE1COMMengOrchestral Epic ActionTCOMPaul Dinletir(ASCAP)TIT13Naomiville Music (ASCAP)")
gi = [len(slovaboli) for slovaboli in slovaboli]
dlinna_c = len(c) - 1
gi = sorted(set(gi))
j, ii, n, i = 0, 0, 0, 0
pez, cif = [], []
for j in range(dlinna_c):
    p = []
    n = 0
    i = j
    ii = 0
    while n < gi[(len(gi) - 1)]:
        while n < gi[ii]:
            p.append(c[i])
            n += 1
            if i < dlinna_c:
                i += 1
            else:
                n = max(gi)
        p = "".join(p)  
        if p in slovaboli:
            pez.append(p)
            cif.append(i - 1)

            j += 1
            p = list(p)
            if ii < (len(gi) - 1):
                ii += 1
            else:
                n = max(gi)
        else:
            p = list(p)
            j += 1
            if ii < (len(gi) - 1):
                ii += 1
            else:
                n = max(gi)


i, j = 0, 0
om, ur = [], []
while j < (len(cif)):
    ur = []
    u = cif[j] - len(pez[j]) + 1
    while i < u:
        ur.append(c[i])
        i += 1
    ur = "".join(ur)
    om.append(ur)
    i = cif[j] + 1
    j += 1       



print(om[0])
om.pop(0)
print("------------")
guum = list(pez[len(pez) - 1])
if (len(c) - 1) == (max(cif) + 1):
    om.append("")
else:
    z = (c[(max(cif) + 1) : len(c)])
    z = "".join(z)
    om.append(z)
for i in range(len(om)):
    print(pez[i], ": ", om[i])
print("------------")
```

с примером кое-как работает вроде